# Is it permissible to read silently in prayer?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, dhikr

Will salah/salat/prayer be accepted if all the Dhikr is made in heart (not even silently).

Example is when you are making Tashshahud and just remember the Dhikr (Attahiyaathu...) in your heart. Not even reading silently.

What is the Hukum of reading Quran this way (in salat and outside of salat) Will it be accepted or not?

Comment: About reading Qur'an scholar's say that the reading for which we earn tawab is that one where our lips move! So even in silent parts of the prayer you should read this way -no matter if one should hear you or not-!

Comment: This link has an answer: https://islamqa.info/en/70577

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib The question primarily here is about reciting in the prayer ,your mention link is only in accordance outside of the prayer.

Answer (score 1):

From Book IV of "Lessons in Islam Talimul Islam" by Mufti Kifayat Ullah Dehlvi (English translation of the Urdu book Talimul Islam)

> Q: Is it allowed for a person not to actually utter the words but only
>   repeat them at the pre-speech level?
>
> A: By only reciting the Holy Quran at the level of imagination, the
>   Salat will not be valid. It is essential to recite it in words.

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

All praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and Companions

**Abu Qatadah narrated that : The Prophet (peace be upon him) said to Abu Bakr: "I passed by you while you were reciting and your voice was low." He said: "I let He who, I was consulting hear." He said: "Raise your voice." Then he said to Umar: "I passed by while you were reciting and your voice was loud." So he said: "I repel drowsiness and keep Ash-Shaitan away." So he said: "Lower your voice."(Tirmidhi)**

Based on the above Narration Scholars have mentioned that During Salah one must recite in a way that a person  is able to hear his own voice with the movement of lips but not loud enough that others could also listen to him and The Dhikr or supplications can be done in heart.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.