# Do you have to move your lips to every syllable in salat?

Tags: salat

When you pray i heard that you must move your lips. I am confused whether or not this is sunnat or fard? Also if you do have to do this, do you have to move your lips to every syllable in salat? I am finding this very hard to do. It took me 25 minutes to pray Dhur and i am feeling very overwhelmed and stressed, instead of relaxed. Please let me know.

Comment: I am not ultra-conservative. However praying is important to me. I just want it to be easy for me. I don't like praying with so much stress so I welcome all opinions.

Comment: @Javeria thats nice if you pray with more concentration but dont focus on time while praying by this means shaitan can move your focus out of salah  causing it to be overwhemed you could see this too http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28137/reading-silently-in-prayer/28140#28140

Answer (score 1):

> *Say, "Call upon Allah or call upon the Most Merciful. Whichever [name] you call - to Him belong the best names." **And do not recite [too] loudly in your prayer or [too] quietly but seek between that an [intermediate] way.*** 
> <sub>[Qur'an [17:110]](http://quran.com/17/110)</sub>

So, while adjusting the volume, you can automatically adjust the movement of your lips, can't you? And I don't think there any Hadith which talk about this matter. So, if someone finds something, please do add it.

Allah knows the best.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you should move your lips while reciting Quran. So it's fard not sunna. But you don't have to pray for 25 minutes!